# how to use ios callkit - call directory extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, callkit

I use iOS CallKit `CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext` to get phone number information, but what I want is to support it by phone number. I'm using Objective-C.

How to customize contacts incoming call?

Where is the guide?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to register names against numbers so that a name from your extension is shown when  that number calls?

Comment: i know  impossible then ...

Comment: I am looking for the same. I think we should use extensions CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext but I'm not sure. Did you find any good tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine custom names for phone numbers with CallDirectory extension. I found this tutorial for you. It is about Voip app, but in the end of it you can find the section for CallDirectory too. With it you can present custom names for phone numbers when a call comes.

It also includes a way to test it.

Link to the tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/150015/callkit-tutorial-ios

More about callDirectory here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit